# React app - 404 page not appearing when typing incorrect url manually post deployment on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, http-status-code-404

I successfully deployed my react app on heroku.com. I am able to navigate to pages only by clicking on the NavLinks that are available on the page.

Problem - the moment I enter anything manually in the url e.g. /contact or /product it does not work and gives the error
"Cannot GET /Contact" or Cannot GET /product. Nor this is show the 404 page available in the app

```
                   <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/" exact element={<Home/>} />
                            <Route path="/*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
                        </Routes>
                    </Suspense>
```

I noticed the same issue for some users on netlify. however, the same fix for SPAs did not work with Heroku.
please advise if there is any solution to this?

I tried this but did not get the expected results

```json
"build": "react-scripts build && echo ‘/\* /index.html 200’ | cat \>build/\_redirects",
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correct, you have two different options on fixing this.

The first and easiest is to use [HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#hashrouter) instead of BrowserRouter. With this component a # is inserted in the urls so that the full url isn't sent to the server but instead managed by React.

The second option is to tell Heroku to let /index.html receive all requests, instead of trying to find /Contact when you request /Contact. I'm not familiar with Heroku so I don't know how to do this.